# Google Cloud Platform DataFlow workers IP addresses

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to know what range of external IP the DataFlow workers on GCP are using? The goal is to set-up some kind of IP filtering on an external service, so that only our DataFlow jobs running on GCP can access the service.

Comment: Do you have more details about what you're trying to do? IP address based filters aren't sufficient to provide security/authentication for a service.

Comment: Sure. So we have a production Kafka cluster running outside of GCP. We would like to process the data from there using DataFlow (using a custom source we developed). However, we would like to reduce exposure of our Kafka cluster. We are running Kafka 0.8.x, so we don't have SSL either, nor authentication baked in the protocol.

Comment: I don't think you can know this up front because the flow might scale dynamically and cannot use a pool of predefined static IPs. And the whole GCE IP range is too large to be useful. My idea would be a VPN? If you really wanna go with IP addresses, the only way I can think of is a script that monitors the dataflow IP addresses and on-the-fly reconfigures your firewall.

Comment: A VPN is an interesting idea. Is it possible to ensure all dataflow workers are members of a particular VPN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to upgrade so that you can use SSL or other mechanisms of strong authentication.

You can use the `--network=` option to control the GCE Network that the worker VMs are assigned to. Take a look at the [GCE docs on networking](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en) for details on how to set up a VPN (like the comment from Elmar suggested). You could also look at setting up a single machine in the network with a static, external IP and using it as a proxy for the other VMs in the network.

This is not a use pattern we have tested, so there may be issues with latency or throughput of traffic through the proxy/VPN. You will likely need to be careful to only send your traffic through this proxy so that you don’t accidentally hijack the traffic used by each worker to communicate with the Dataflow service.